# Android Studio 3.2: where is cmake message() output displayed?

Tags: c++, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio. I'm working on a project that has a relevant C++ part which relies on a cmakelist.txt file. Is there a way to display the output coming from some message(STATUS …..) commands placed into my cmakelist.txt during the sync phase? What I have in mind is something similar to the "cmake" view in CLion IDE.

Answer (score 4):

What the output file is named seems to be different for me, so I guess it keeps changing.

I found the output by including this in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
message(STATUS "TEST STATUS")
```

Building, and then running:

```
fgrep "TEST STATUS" -r .
```

From my project directory.

The manoeuvring required to get the even most basic of information from the build pretty much sums up Android development.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in $your-proj/$your-module/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/$ARCH/cmake_build_output.txt, where

- $your-module by default is "app", yours might differ
- $ARCH is your CPU arch-type (armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a x86_64 etc)

In the same directory, you could see other two files that are useful for debugging

- cmake_build_command.txt
- android_gradle_build.json

In the future releases, the ".externalNativeBuiold" directory name/location might change; but for now, it is the name of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

The output is actually in `.cxx/cmake/debug/$ANDROID_ABI`